# Type inaccessible dynamic type is not implicitly convertible to expected type

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
import "./strings.sol";


contract XFinance {
   using strings for *;

    address addr;
   uint coin;
   Shipment shipment;

function XFinance(uint balance) {
    coin=balance;
    shipment=new Shipment();

  }  



function changeShipmentStatus(string shipmentId,string st,address driverAddress){

            shipment.setShipmentId(shipmentId);
            shipment.setStatusOfShipment(st);
        processPayment(driverAddress);
}

function processPayment(address driverAddress){
    string currentStatus=shipment.getStatusOfShipment();
    if(currentStatus.toSlice().equals('RAP'.toSlice())){
        shipment.setAddressOfDiver1(driverAddress);
        sendPayment(driverAddress);
    }
    else if(currentStatus.toSlice().equals('DAL'.toSlice())){
        shipment.setAddressOfDiver2(driverAddress);
        sendPayment(driverAddress);
    }

    else
    if(currentStatus.toSlice().equals('ATD'.toSlice())){
        shipment.setAddressOfDriver3(driverAddress);
        sendPayment(driverAddress);
    }
}


function sendPayment(address beneficiary) payable returns(bool success) {
  if(msg.value==0) throw;
  if(!beneficiary.send(msg.value)) throw;
  return true;
}

function getBalance() returns(uint){
    return coin; 
}

function getStatus() returns(string){
    return shipment.statusOfShipment;
}

function getAddress() returns(address){
    return addr; 
}

}


contract Shipment{
    string public shipmentId;
    string public statusOfShipment;
    address public driver1;
    address public driver2;
    address public driver3;

    function Shipment(){}


    function setShipmentId(string shId){
    shipmentId=shId;
    }
    function getShipmentId() returns(string){
    return shipmentId;
    }

    function setStatusOfShipment(string st){
    statusOfShipment=st;
    }
    function getStatusOfShipment() returns(string){
    return statusOfShipment;
    }

    function setAddressOfDriver1(address d1){
    driver1=d1;
    }
    function getAddressOfDriver1() returns(address){
    return driver1;
    }

    function setAddressOfDriver2(address d2){
    driver2=d2;
    }
    function getAddressOfDriver2() returns(address){
    return driver2;
    }

    function setAddressOfDriver3(address d3){
    driver3=d3;
    }
    function getAddressOfDriver3() returns(address){
    return driver3;
    }
}
```

This is my contract

I get error while compiling it

```
C:/Users/User(LPT-APR2015-02)/solidity-experiments/contracts/XFinance.sol:35:2: Error: Type inaccessible dynamic type
is not implicitly convertible to expected type string storage pointer.
        string currentStatus=shipment.getStatusOfShipment();
        ^-------------------------------------------------^
,C:/Users/User(LPT-APR2015-02)/solidity-experiments/contracts/XFinance.sol:37:3: Error: Member "setAddressOfDiver1" no
t found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract Shipment
                shipment.setAddressOfDiver1(driverAddress);
                ^-------------------------^
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was unable to completely correct this because I'm not sure of the contents of `strings.sol`.

The problem is dynamic length `string` can't be passed between contracts, *yet*.

The `string` type is very awkward due to its dynamic length and the fact that a character is not necessarily a single byte. As a general guideline, consider using `bytes32` and offloading conversion chores to front-ends.

Fixed-length `bytes32` is more gas-efficient and *natural* for the EVM. You won't have any problem passing them around.

Hope this helps.

Comment: strings.sol is library to perform string operations available @ https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils#concatenating-strings

Comment: Sorry can't find what's the actual storage cost of `bytes32`. Does it pre-allocate and cap total capacity of the variable to 32 bytes as the name suggest?

Answer (score 1):

It is supported since solidity 0.4.22;

> [Changelog](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/Changelog.md#0422-2018-04-16): - Support accessing dynamic return data in post-byzantium
>   EVMs.

Comment: Do you know how we can take advantage of this during local development? My local install of `solc` is `Version: 0.4.24+commit.e67f0147.Darwin.appleclang` but in web3py I compile my contracts with `evm_version=='homestead'`