# Solidity return type string showing inaccessible

Tags: solidity, string, data-types

Smart contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract PassData{


    PassData passData;
    string s;
    function PassData(){
        s="come";
    }

    function getData() returns(string){
        return s;
    }

    function accessData(address contractAddress) returns(string){
        passData=PassData(contractAddress);
        return passData.getData();
    }


}
```

Error

> browser/Untitled.sol:18:16: Error: Return argument type inaccessible
>   dynamic type is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of
>   first return variable) string memory.
>           return passData.getData();
>                  ^----------------^

is there any other way to return the string in solidity?

Also tried returns(string memory) but still same error.

I know we can store byte32 and return easily but I want as a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12765/type-inaccessible-dynamic-type-is-not-implicitly-convertible-to-expected-type

Comment: The simple answer is that you cannot (yet) return a string to another Solidity caller: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html#can-you-return-an-array-or-a-string-from-a-solidity-function-call

Answer (score 1):

Your code has error, i updated, as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract PassData{


    string s;

    function PassData(){
        s="come";
    }

    function getData() constant returns(string){
        return s;
    }

    function setData(string _string) {
        s = _string;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps ~

Comment: I don't want to constant getData() function. As my question is there any way to return string variable?

Comment: The dynamic length string can't be passed between contracts~

Answer (score 0):

In the example you gave, all of `accessData()` should be running outside the blockchain. Then your contract reduces to:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract PassData{

  string public s;

  function PassData(){
    s="stored";
  }
}
```

The web3.js code would run something like:

```
abi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"s","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]
PassData = web3.eth.contract(abi);
passData = PassData.new();
console.log(passData.s());
```

---

**Edit~**

I was kind of winging the web3.js version above. After the poster mentioned issues creating the contract, I wanted to confirm the exact code, but Python is the only test environment I have up and handy. Directly addressing the "ropsten network" error that comeback4you mentioned in the comment is starting to get pretty far removed from the original question.

In the meantime, here is verified [web3.py](https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py) code, with Python 3:

```
from web3 import Web3, TestRPCProvider

web3 = Web3(TestRPCProvider())

PassData = web3.eth.contract(
                  contract_name='PassData',
                  bytecode="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",
                  abi=[{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"s","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":False,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":False,"type":"constructor"}],
              )

txid = PassData.deploy()

receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txid)

passData = PassData(receipt.contractAddress)

print(passData.call().s())
```

which outputs `stored`

Comment: I tried you code .. I didn't see any result from console.log(). And when I instantiated, eth complains that I should use ropsten network. I have already fired up testrpc, and it even communicated with my migration

Comment: I don't want to public 's' variable. As my question is there any way to return string variable?