# How to copy a string field from one contract to another?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, string

I want one contract to be able to copy fields from another.

```
contract Klendathu {
  string public bugs;

  function Klendathu(string _bugs) public {
    bugs = _bugs;
  }
}

contract RogerYoung {
  string public bugs;

  function getBugsFromKlendathu(Klendathu bigK) public {
    bugs = bigK.bugs();
  }
}
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: Type inaccessible dynamic type is not implicitly convertible to expected type string storage ref.
        bugs = bigK.bugs();
               ^---------^
```

How do I copy a `string` from one contract to another?

Answer (score 4):

The reason behind this problem is that currently [the EVM is unable to read variably-sized data from external function calls](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3788/8469) i.e. strings.

[consider whether using bytes32[] instead of strings in this instance](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/12767/8469) would be a suitable alternative - and offload the heavy lifting of converting from/to string for the UI to the middleware.

```
contract Klendathu {
  bytes32 public bugs;

  function Klendathu(bytes32 _bugs) public {
    bugs = _bugs;
  }
}

contract RogerYoung {
  bytes32 public bugs;

  function getBugsFromKlendathu(Klendathu bigK) public {
    bugs = bigK.bugs();
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  In one case of my actual code a bytes32 will suffice quite nicely. In the other I guess my only option is to use a dedicated contract to hold the string I need.  It's a JOSE encrypted blob of data of uncertain length. That way it can be passed around as an address.