# Contract Using An Interface Is Not Compiling

Tags: solidity, inheritance, interfaces

I am learning Solidity and I am using Remix to experiment and enhance my learning. I am currently trying to create a simple contract that uses an Interface.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract InterfaceWithMe {

    function call() returns (string);

}

contract Interfacing {

    address ckAddress = 0x9fe1c58215407d67719ba680360940056e5eceb7;
    InterfaceWithMe daContract = InterfaceWithMe(ckAddress);

    function call() returns (string) {
        return daContract.call();
    }
```

When I try an compile this on Remix, I get the following type error on line 14:

TypeError:Return argument type inaccessible dynamic type is not implicitely convertibel to expected type (type of first return variable) string memory.

Here is the other contract that I use to interface with this contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract InterfaceWithMe {

    function call() returns (string) {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm suggesting the answer is [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/12767/47702) and the [another one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46527/47702)

Answer (score 1):

A fair bit of fiddling for readability and style.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Interface {
    function call() public pure returns (string);
    function isInterface() public pure returns(bool);
}

contract Interfacing {

    Interface daContract; 

    constructor(address theContract) public {
        daContract = Interface(theContract);
        require(daContract.isInterface());
    }

    function call() public view returns (string) {
        return daContract.call();
    }

}

contract InterfaceWithMe is Interface {

    function call() public pure returns (string) {
        return "Hello";
    }

    function isInterface() public pure returns(bool) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here it is in Remix to show it working.

1. Deploy `InterfaceWithMe`
2. Copy the deployed address to the clipboard.
3. Deploy `Interfacing` passing the address from the clipboard into the constructor.
4. Call `call` in `Interfacing.
5. `Hello`

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have some follow up questions for you. Why does InterfaceWithMe need to inherit from Interface? Shouldn't Interfacing inherit from Interface?

Comment: It's about when to use composition and when to use inheritance. `Camry is Car` so it must implement all the standard inherited functions. `Driver` starts `Car` so that will cast and instance of something as a type `Car` and then invoke it with `myCar.start ()`. Note that the compiler can see the source code to work out the interface.

Comment: Why contract Interfacing existence. Is necessary that bridge ti implement the interface? Thx